# Replace the argument with a list in R

Tags: r, argument-passing

Some times there is a function which has an arbitrary number of arguments. For example, the `bootstrapPage` function of package shiny. If I have a data.frame and I want to create one widget for one row, then I have not figured out a pretty way to pass the number of arguments according to the row number of the data.frame. So far, I generate the script and use the trick of `eval(parse(text="..."))`

In fact, the structure of arguments passed to function in R (key and value) is similar to a `list`, so I am wondering if there is a way to pass the argument as a list in R.

More specifically, if I have a function `f` and a list `argv`, is there a way to pass the objects in `argv` to `f` according to the matching of the name of `argv` and the name of the arguments of `f`, and the position in `argv` and the position in the arguments of `f`?

For example, let

```
f <- function(a, b) a + b
argv <- list(a=1, b=2)
```

How should I pass the `argv` to `f` which is equivalent to `f(a=argv$a, b=argv$b)`?

Or if we have:

```
f <- function(a, b, ...) { # some codes }
argv <- list(a = 1, b = 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

How should I pass the `argv` to `f` which is equivalent to `f(a=argv$a, b=argv$b, argv[[3]], argv[[4]], argv[[5]])`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are looking for `do.call`.

```
do.call(f, argv)
```

Here are some examples

```
> args <- list(n = 10, mean = 3, sd = .5)
> do.call(rnorm, args)
 [1] 3.589416 3.393031 2.928506 2.503925 3.316584 2.581787 2.686507 3.178877
 [9] 3.083885 2.821506
> do.call(rnorm, list(10, 3, .5))
 [1] 3.964526 2.838760 2.436684 3.068581 1.842332 3.739046 4.050525 3.097042
 [9] 3.665041 3.535947
> f <- function(a, b) a + b
> argv <- list(a=1, b=2)
> do.call(f, argv)
[1] 3
> f <- function(a, b, ...){print(a);print(b);print(sum(...))}
> argv <- list(a=1,b=2, 3, 4, 5)
> do.call(f, argv)
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 12
```

Comment: Nice collection of examples. This is a feature of the language that really deserves better treatment in the "introduction to R".

Comment: +1  for the great examples